# How to group by two fields altogether in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table:

```
gw_id |gw_payload |gw_name |gw_ref |gw_time             |gw_created_time     |
------|-----------|--------|-------|--------------------|--------------------|
1     |aaa        |PHP     |0.1.1  |2015-11-11 11:34:41 |2015-11-11 13:59:44 |
2     |bbb        |PHP     |0.1.1  |2015-11-11 11:34:41 |2015-11-11 13:59:57 |
3     |ccc        |RUBY    |0.1.2  |2015-11-10 01:34:41 |2015-11-10 13:59:57 |
4     |ddd        |RUBY    |0.1.4  |2015-11-10 02:34:41 |2015-11-10 16:59:57 |
```

I want to grab records group by `gw_name` and I want to get the latest `gw_ref` and latest `gw_time`. So I want below:

```
gw_name |gw_ref_max |gw_time_max         |
--------|-----------|--------------------|
RUBY    |0.1.4      |2015-11-10 02:34:41 |
PHP     |0.1.1      |2015-11-11 11:34:41 |
```

I'm using this SQL, it works, but I don't think it's correct, I'm worried:

```
select gw_name, max(gw_ref) as gw_ref_max, max(gw_time) as gw_time_max      
from tbl group by gw_name order by gw_time,gw_created_time desc
```

So what is correct SQL I should write?

Comment: The SQL statement seems fine to me. Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: you want to get  `latest gw_ref and latest gw_time` or ' `latest gw_ref and the gw_time corresponding to it`. If you want both latest then your query seems ok. If you want `latest gw_ref and the gw_time corresponding to it`, then you include condition in WHERE clause to check gw_ref = (select max(gw_ref) from ...).

Comment: @PK20, yes I want to corresponding latest to the `gw_name`, @Mureinik, I'm worried because I don't think I can use max() on the string (`gw_ref`) field.

Comment: I think you can use max() for string. Did you try it out. What results did you get when you tried to get max(gw_ref).

Comment: @PK20, Actually my SQL used max() already, it seems right, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

What if `max(gw_ref)` is not the latest in the group according to `gw_created_time`?

Usually you should use ROW_NUMBER() per group to order records inside of each group and then select records with `ROW_NUMBER = 1`. In MySQL there is no ROW_NUMBER() aggregate function but you can use [User-Defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) in MySQL to emulate ROW_NUMBER()

```
select *
from (
   select gw_id,gw_ref,gw_time,gw_created_time,
          @num := if(@grp = gw_name, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
          @grp := gw_name as dummy
  from tbl,(select @num := 0, @grp := null) as T
  order by gw_created_time DESC
) as x where x.row_number = 1;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c9b7/3)</kbd>

Also look at:
[How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

Comment: Where is `tbl` in this case?

Comment: @Phoenix: I've changed table name in the answer to tbl.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get latest `gw_ref` and `gw_time` corresponding to it, you can use subquery.

```
select * from (
    select gw_name, gw_ref, gw_time
    from tbl
    order by gw_ref desc, gw_time desc, gw_created_time desc
) as s
group by s.gw_name
```

Be careful to ordering by `gw_ref`, which can takes values like **0.1.10** (this is greater than **0.1.2**). You can try ordering by [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).